# Resize UITableView's height to be as high as it needs to fit only total content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, ios6

So I am having a very basic issue. I have this `UITableView` within a `view`, and I would like to make this table's height as high as it needs to be to display ALL the rows within the table. Therefore, I don't want to be able to scroll, I just want all the rows to appear. (The rows are dynamic in quantity and `height`).

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize cellSize = [[[_stepsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]content] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(528.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return cellSize.height;
}
```

If there are 20 rows, the table will be very high, but if there is only 1 row, it will be very small and the other content will not appear 19 rows below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if I understand it correctly, you should be able to add up the height for each row and adjust the tableview height based on that:

```
CGFloat tableHeight = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < [_stepsArray count]; i ++) {
    tableHeight += [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
}
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, tableHeight);
```

you can do this immediately after [tableView reloadData]

Comment: I never call a [tableView reloadData]. Where should I put this then?

Comment: after you are done setting up _stepsArray (which I'm assuming is your datasource).

Comment: Isn't heightForRowAtIndexPath going to be called twice with that? Also... isn't there a much simpler way to do this? I feel like I have seen sooo many apps where table's height are based off the total number of rows..! Thanks!

Comment: it will get called twice but should be relatively inexpensive since you are just calculating content size based on font. You could also try just setting the tableView's frame height to tableView.contentSize.height after the it is finished displaying (you can do this in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath)

Answer (score 6):

Here is more simpler solution: All you need is to set `sizeToFit` on your `UITableView`, after it has been populated with cells. If you set `delegate` and `dataSource` through `xib`, you can do this in your `viewDidLoad` method, or `viewDidAppear`, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [yourTableView sizeToFit];
}
```

But, if you add `delegate` and `dataSource` somewhere in the code, you have to put `sizeToFit` after this:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    [yourTableView setDelegate:self];
    [yourTableView setDataSource:self];

    [yourTableView sizeToFit];
}
```

Also, you have to do this after reloadTable, if you do that somewhere.

This will resize your table exactly to height which is a sum of its cells height!

Comment: That's right DennisWelu, **sizeToFit** will consider only row's content, not whitespaces between rows.

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this,

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        NSLog(@"%f",your_tableView.contentSize.height);
    }
}
```

In **Swift 3.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?.row {
        print("\(tableView.contentSize.height)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an observer for the contentSize property on the table view, and adjust the frame size accordingly

In viewDidLoad add the following line of code

```
[your_tableview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:0 context:NULL];
```

then in the callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
         CGRect frame = your_tableview.frame;
         frame.size = your_tableview.contentSize;
         your_tableview.frame = frame;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Set a height constraint on the table, connect to an outlet, and add the following to your view controller:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tableViewHeightContraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`
That will solve your problem.