# How to get tableviwe to fit content using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Im rting to figure out how to get a tableviews height to change depending upon the content in the tableview. I cant allow the tablevoew to go further than its bounds of the superview. But i can have the tableview be anywhere in between the bounds of the superview, so it can shrink grow all that other good stuff depending upon the content. What i did was set the top, leading and trailing constraints but left the botton constraint out thinking it would scale the tableview to the needed height but that didint work. Any idea?

---

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_settings_tableview
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:20]];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_settings_tableview
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:20]];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_settings_tableview
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:-20]];
       //Trying to figure out what constraint this should be [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_settings_tableview
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:450]];
```

This is what i already have written im trying to figure out what the bottom costraint should be in order to allow the tableview to grow to its contents size

Comment: You may be able to achieve this by making an outlet from your Constraint to the View and then within the view you can adjust the Constraint with the constant variable. Once you've finished you're changes you will probably need to call setLayoutIfNeeded on your view as well for the changes to take effect (you can also do this in a animation block as well if you want the change to be animated). I haven't really tested this yet, but I remember a project a while ago were I needed to do something similar.

Comment: I do al my code programaticlalay not in IB. I hate IB really but i see what your saying. The issue is im going to want to size the tableviwe for all phones the iPhone 5,6 and 6 and also the iPad when im writing universal code. Honestly there should be a BOOL function in there by apple that says. Want to size to fit content. I dont know why they havent implemented that yet

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13574193/2082569

Pasting the solution here for easy reference, basically you are calculating the height of cells and setting it to tableview's frame-

```
CGFloat tableHeight = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < [_stepsArray count]; i ++) {
    tableHeight += [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
}
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, tableHeight);
```

the only thing thats missing is you don't want it to go beyond the superview's bounds, so for that you can use `MIN` method like this-

```
MIN(self.view.frame.size.height, tableHeight);
```

Optionally you can checkout this answer, which uses sizeToFit approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202699/2082569

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tanks for your answer but thats not what i was looking for. I already know how to do this numerous of ways without Autolayout. I trying to figure out the correct bottom constraint to build in order to make the tableview grow with its contents