# Remove extra cells/rows whitespace without data appearing on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I m populating UITableView with data and works fine too.

But my issue is , when the UITableView has less number of rows of data it shows rows with data properly but shows a whitespace . 
For example: if the tableview has 1 row to display it shows that row then under that there are whitespaces like empty rows. 
 I tried

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

and

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

But both just removed the Cell borders not the extra whitespace appearing. 
Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Edit :

Select Button is not Part of the Cell. Just trying to Click on Select Button and then the UITableView Displays under it. ( Like a DropDown ).
Also , using default Tableview Cell not a Custom TableView Cell

Code :

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cityList.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cityCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.cityList[row].cityEn
        print("CityName" + self.cityList[row].cityEn )

        return cell
    }
```

StoryBoard ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Is the Select button part of the cell or what in the screenshot is a cell and what is not?

Comment: is it section or row ?

Comment: Please post some code how you setup the cell.

Comment: Edited Question @Tapani

Comment: Please post some code. You may need to set the number of sections properly

Comment: Number of sections set as 1 , have added code . Please check @MikeG .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @choli answer You can do 2 things,

1. adjust the height of the table view based on the rows,
   [Resize UITableView's height to be as high as it needs to fit only total content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574071/resize-uitableviews-height-to-be-as-high-as-it-needs-to-fit-only-total-content)
2. Simpler solution would be to clear table background color

   `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
   tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the empty cells set the TableView style from Plain to Grouped.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I would comment, but not enough reputation:

This is the tableView size, whenever the full tableview is not filled with rows, it shows some extra rows that are empty. If you don't want this, then you have different possibilities:

- you could make the size of the tableView smaller - e.g. the number of cells * cellHeight
- you can change the appearance of the tableView, so it will be clearColor instead of white, so the placeholder cells will be invisible.

Comment: Have added StoryBoard screenshot. Have used ClearColor propertt already